# Sentiment classification from Smiles-data need

Tags: data-request, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for data that are classified according to the smiles, for example :( is negative sentiment (labeled may be -1, :) is positive sentiment (labeled may be 1). I know twitter has such data set, but I am not sure where to find it actually. If the data set looks like this,

```
label     text
-1       I am sad :(
 0       this is a mango
 1       I am so happy today :)
```

Suggesting pls.

Comment: Can't you just "search" for the text ":)" and then put a +1 next to it? p.s. you can search twitter for ":)" https://twitter.com/search?q=%22%3A%29%22&src=typd

Comment: I am actually not expert in data scraping twitter, just a beginner. still trying to download. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There are lots of good libraries, so you shouldn't have to do anything from scratch https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries - check out the Twitter console to use the API without programming https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console